# MIT AppInventor: target every component

Tags: android, button, properties, block, app-inventor

I would like to modify every Button's property, but I can't target them all. I can target only one at a time. I tried to use the Any Component menu's Any Button block, but still, I can target only one Button. I can't perform modifications manually (block by block), because I'm working with many buttons (254, to be exact). I tried putting every Button in a list, but dragging 254 blocks (one-by-one) takes too much time. Any solutions?

Comment: You might want to think about redesigning your app. Do you really need 254 buttons at the same time on a screen? You will work at the limit of App Inventor and probably not be able to build your app anymore. Try to use only a few buttons and reuse them or use a listpicker instead.

Comment: @Taifun Yes, I need 254 buttons at the same time, on the same screen. I can't use a ListPicker, because I need to show images, too... I've tried some alternatives, but this was the only way I could find to accomplish my goal. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: my [thumbnail listview example](https://puravidaapps.com/listview.php) might be an alternative

Answer (score 0):

One good way to effectively change several properties of components ( of the same type. i.e Buttons), is to use a for-each loop then incorporating it with the any-button.property.

To use a for-each loop, you must first populate a list of components, **however**, buttons cannot be directly added to lists (structure limitations..), but fret not! there is a way to bypass this, which is to first create an empty list, named buttonsList (or whatever you like, labeled clearly), then to populate the list at screen initialization, with all buttons (to automate the process, **this must be done manually at least once**

After populating the list with all buttons, you'll then be able to change all properties using the for each loop.

1. initiate global-buttonsList : create empty list;
2. when screen1.initialize

   - do add item to 'buttonsList'

     - add all buttons here

       - Button1
       - Button2
       - Button#...etc.
3. At trigger event

   - for each - 'buttons/component name' in - Global 'buttonsList'

     - set anyButton.property (e.g, text?)

       - of component - 'buttons/component name'

         - to - "property change"
         - (i.e: text- Hello World!)

This should get the job done. Nevertheless, like @Taifun mentioned...that's a lot of buttons, and if there's one thing appInventor is really good at, it's crashing, so restructuring of the app would be great if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is a clear answer. This describes perfectly what I tried the first time, however, I gave up populating the buttons into a list, because dragging those block takes some time. In this case, your answer isn't an efficient solution, so I can't accept it. @Taifun mentioned, that he had a thumbnail listview example for AppInventor. This approach might be a permanent solution for people who have similar problems with the interface design. And it is a space- and memory-efficient example too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "Horizontal Arrangements" with your buttons (sorry only manually)
then change "Any-component" with the property for the button  (color,text-color...)
and target them with the numbers from the Loop (for each number)

[image]